# Java gradle project debugger is not showing variables information

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea

So I have a problem for which google did yield no results. When debugging gradle project I can not see actual values in some of collections or the values are showing differently compared to maven project. Test case: create empty maven and gradle projects with code:

```
final EnumSet<NumberEnum> numberEnum = EnumSet.of(NumberEnum.ONE, NumberEnum.THREE);
final List<String> texts = Arrays.asList("A", "b", "c");
final Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("a", "b");
map.put("c", "d");
map.put("v", "d");

// ----
public enum NumberEnum {
  ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

When debugging maven project, this is what I can see of values:
[image: maven-demo]
Which is clear and informative.
Now, when I run same example on gradle project, this is the result:
[image: gradle-demo]
I can access map and list values by navigating debug structure, but there's no way to access enum values without evaluating and re-collecting values with `stream()` to list.

These are demo projects created with IntelliJ and without adding nothing extra. Both are launched using `Application` configuration to run main class of IntelliJ. They are both using `oracle 1.8 jdk`. Gradle version is `6.7`.
Does anyone have an idea why it happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij 2020.3 problem. Reverting to 2020.1 fixes this issue. I did create a ticket on [jetbrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260040?clearDraft=true&description=%0A%0AIU-203.6682.168,%20JRE%2011.0.9.1%2B11-b1145.63x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o.,%20OS%20Mac%20OS%20X(x86_64)%20v10.16,%20screens%203584.0x2240.0;%20Retina)